# Converting unix timestamp into time

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, unix

So I want to convert unix timestamp into date time object, I am trying to do this with :

```
 async function getTime(unix){
  var date = new Date(unix * 1000);
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var mins = "0" + date.getMinutes();
  var secs = "0" + date.getSeconds();
  var formattedTime = hours + ':' + mins.substr(-2) + ':' + secs.substr(-2);

}
```

but I keep getting

```
Promise { undefined }
```

on the table. can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: add `return formattedTime`

Comment: Your question is about converting a unix timestamp in to a date time object which is done on the first line of your function. It does not mention formatting the date at any point other than what's in your code. Nor do you show us the code that calls it or what you're expecting back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I can see your function, you don't return anything. You have to return the variable that you want. Also, there are no async calls within this function so it seems useless to make this an async function.

To add to this, the variable you want to return is probably formattedTime.

```
function getTime(unix) {
  const date = new Date(unix * 1000);
  const hours = date.getHours();
  const mins = "0" + date.getMinutes();
  const secs = "0" + date.getSeconds();
  return hours + ':' + mins.substr(-2) + ':' + secs.substr(-2);
}
```

Please note: I am using const, may that not be possible to use, use var instead.